# 13th Chords Movable in Minor Thirds?

Tags: chords

How are these 13th chords still "in key" when moved up in minor thirds?  If I'm thinking in key of GM, next up from G13 would be A#13; A# isn't in key of G major....(?)

Comment: I believe you forgot to attach some context to this question. Also, in the key of G major, G13 is not diatonic.

Comment: Also, G to A# is technically an augmented second; G to Bb would be a minor third :)

Comment: The short answer is: they are not in key. But the real question seems to be: why do you need to know that?

Comment: Robben Ford, in one of his Truefire courses, said that moving a G13 in minor 3rds will still remain "in the proper key".  His lesson was discussing 13ths, and he was using a G13-C13-D13 progression.  I'm an amateur and confused more than usual 

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be missing context to this question, but I'll fill in some assumptions.

These thirteenth chords are *dominant* thirteenth chords.

Also, these dominant thirteenth chords would purportedly be *diatonic* dominant thirteenth chords.

There is only one *diatonic* dominant chord in any major/minor key.

In the key of `G` major the diatonic dominant thirteenth chord is `D13`. All other dominant thirteenth chords will be *chromatic* in the key of `G` major. Those chromatic dominant thirteenth chords may have secondary dominant function, be non-functional, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Robben Ford is a blues player, and it's likely when he talks about being 'in key' it's not in the more strict sense of diatonic harmony. The other answers have pointed this out clearly, so I won't repeat.

However in blues, and to a large extent jazz, you can move around pentatonic scales and get easy 'hacks' to new sounds while playing very familiar pentatonic scales. Blues is built on dominant 7th's, you would usually say that all chords in a blues progression are I, IV and V , or similar but all the chords changed to be dominant 7ths. This straight away makes it not that compatible with diatonic harmony but you can think of it as a style/tradition feature of blues.

In this context, the 13th chord, or perhaps more accurately the pentatonic scale that outlines it, CAN be moved up a minor 3rd as a technique/sound hack that more or less works with the root 7th chord.

In a G blues, if you play the Bb pentatonic over the 'tonic' G7 chord you outline the intervals #9, 4, 5, b7, 1. This is FAR from diatonic by any common analysis, but in the somewhat murky waters of the blues it still hits broadly 'correct' tones for the G7, with the added dissonance of the #9, but that's a common 'blue note' used anyway.

I can't be sure, but I think he is suggesting that playing the pentatonic scale (which roughly correlates to a 13th chord) moved up a minor 3rd still contains all useable notes against a given blues 'tonic' and may be an easy way to use a familiar fingering on guitar to easily add some interest to playing.

Going up a further b3, well it's still much the same thing but the resulting intervals get a lot more dissonant. But it's still a useable sound if you learn it, with a familiar fingering.

Using pentatonics, which fall under the fingers very nicely on guitar, we can easily find more sounds for solos. moving them around is an easy way of exploring more 'out' solos while still making very coherent musical sounds, as our ears hear the pentatonic 'coherence' and forgive the dissonance compared to a more strict definition of key. I think that's maybe what he is getting at here.

You can do the same for other chords other than 7th's. It's approaching the problem in reverse, rather than learn a new scale pattern for each sound you want to create just take a familiar one (the pentatonic scale) and work out how those much played scales with tonnes of muscle memory can be used if laid over a stated harmony with various different roots.

I have a book somewhere that analyses all pentatonic scales built off each root for most chords you are likely to experience, and what the resulting 'sound' will be. In this way they hope to unlock many different sounds and ways of coherently playing 'out' while still maintaining a familiar shape on the instrument. I use snippets of it in my playing, as I can construct a coherent pentatonic line based on the b5 of a chord (when that works) and dissolve it to another coherent pentatonic line on the b3 and finally the pentatonic scale on the 1. The result is I sound like I have played 'very out', then 'a bit out', then 'very in' when all I was really doing is playing pentatonic boxes on varying roots. Melodically coherent because the shape is very familiar, but hopefully fairly interesting as a new harmonic exploration in a solo.

I THINK thats what he is talking about here, without further context..

Comment: Well said.  Thanks for your time on that answer.  As a teacher myself, I know very well that one unclear word or two can send a student into a confusion spiral.  I may be coming  out of it now.  Being a math nerd obsessed with detail has its drawbacks

Answer (score 2):

13th chords consist of ^1 ^3 ^5 ^♭7 ^9 ^11 and ^13. Often ^11 is omitted, and so is ^5 on some instruments, notably guitar.

So, in key G, G B D F A C E are the maximum notes used.

Moving up (or down) by whatever interval, be it a semitone or m3, and taking all the notes up/down by the same interval, will give other 13th chords. Including A♯, better termed as B♭, which is actually the minor third above G - A♯ is not, as pointed out in comments.

And, if moving up by m3, why should *any* of the new notes belong to the old key..?

Comment: That's what was confusing me.

Comment: Regarding your last question, only two notes of a Bb13 chord are different from the notes of the G13 chord, and they are the two least important (in jazz, which is a reasonable context to assume for any question about 13th chords) notes of the Bb13 chord: the root and the 5th. Oh wait, three notes. The A has to be flat as well. Hmmm. That still leaves more than half the notes intact but it makes a lot less sense to me.

Comment: How about this. Bb13 in the context of C major (since a G13 is dominant) gives a flat 3, flat 6 and flat 7, so it’s in the parallel minor of the G13 chord. So maybe in the Beethoven sense of major and minor modes are still the “same key” they are in the same key?